# MySQL "#2006 - MySQL server has gone away" in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, debian

**The Problem**

My MySQL database works fine for my web application. However, when I try to open the database with phpMyAdmin, I get this error message:

```
#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
```

And phpMyAdmin disconnects back to the login screen. Other databases work fine.
My `ax_allowed_packet` is set to 16. I also tried 64, but it didn't work.

Also this error occured eventually. The database is about 3 MB in size, so not very big.

**Used Software**

- Debian Squeeze x64
- MySQL (current version)
- phpMyAdmin (current version)

**Question**

How can I fix this error in order to view and edit my database in phpMyAdmin again?

Comment: `max_allowed_packet` set to 16? Dont't forget M (16M, 32M)?

Comment: Don't worry, I did not forget the 'M'.

Comment: Having the same issue now, Most queries work fine, but whenever I do something like execute a (valid) sql script through phpmyadmin it gives this error

Comment: having the same issues, this is very annoying especially when trying to debug this with all the settings, if i can add a detail, i started having this problem when i updated mysql to 5.6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally found it.

Apparently, there were some incompatibility issues after upgrading to MySQL 5.6.

In order to check for such issues and fix them, you will need to do a MySQL Upgrade.

Just run the following on a terminal:

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

Enter your password, and wait until the upgrade finishes.

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I currently don't have this problem anymore, but when I have it again, I will try your solution

Comment: Thank you for this answer, 99% of other solutions i found with google searches were always about mysql query timeout.

Comment: i still face the same issue, I have done mysql_upgrade, increased size

Comment: have you tried increasing the max_allowed_paquet config variable in my.cnf too?

Comment: The upgrade command did some things but failed in the end. However, it DID fix the problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My Reputation is not high enough so i can't comment so i will here, mysql_upgrade -u root -p worked for me i had the same issue, after upgrading mysql, everything  worked. i could could log into the database using phpmyadmin but when i tried to add a user it failed , giving MySQL “#2006 - MySQL server has gone away”, Note that i also updated phpmyadmin with yum update phpmyadmin first before running  mysql_upgrade -u root -p.
Now all works fine, thanks!