# phpMyAdmin logs out immediately after log in

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have recently ran into a problem with my phpmyadmin. I have been using phpmyadmin smoothly to log in to a remote server. However today when I attempt to log in, it gives me the error #2006 cannot log in to MYSQL server. However if I click the "GO" button again, it logs me in, then when I click a button, it logs me out and says my session has expired. I have set the timeout time longer than 1440 in the php.ini. but that did not cease the problem. How do I fix this? Not only that but this is not the first time i have run into problems with phpmmyadmin, why does phpmyadmin behave weird overtime even when the config files are not tampered with?

Comment: Your problem sounds a lot like this one: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461648/mysql-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away-in-phpmyadmin

Hope it helps

Comment: @Pantera96c thank you for the response however it is not exactly, also the solution does not work.